# Why is Orchard auto-encoding strings to the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

In my driver, I am passing the dynamic object to the view, but it is automatically encoding all my strings which is mangling the links I am constructing in the view.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public class SomeWidgetDriver : ContentPartDriver<SomeWidgetPart>
{
    // GET
    protected override DriverResult Display(SomeWidgetPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_SomeWidget",
            () => shapeHelper.Parts_SomeWidget(
                AppUrl: part.AppUrl,
                AppVersion: part.AppVersion,
                RenderTo: part.RenderTo,
                Test: "xxxx&"));
    }
}
```

When I add the below to the view:

```
@Model.Test
```

It renders like this:

```
xxxx&amp;
```

Is there a way to stop this from happening? I am trying to get it to exactly render "xxxx&".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this has to do with Orchard at all.
In Razor everything is html encoded.
Did you try:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Test)
```

?